# Default Customer filter doesn't show customers - Multi company in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have enabled `multicompany` in odoo 10. and created a mother company and two child companies. 
And then created customers one for child_company_A and one for child_company_B. When i click on menu `Customers`, display empty list with filter `customers`. if i remove filter it displays all customer.

What is the reason for filter not working?

How can i resolve it?

And what is use of `parent_id` in customer form view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cosutmer filter is like this:

```xml
<filter string="Customers" name="customer" domain="[('customer','=',1), ('parent_id', '=', False)]"/>
```

so if you select the filter records with parent_id are not shown.

if you have a costumer that is a company and you create an employee that work there no need to show them the parent company is enough.

Comment: if create a customer in own company it won't display if use `customer` filter.

Comment: If you login using super user do you see records

Comment: if filter is on, NO.

Comment: This problem occurred when i assign `parent_id` in customer form.

What is the use of `parent_id` in customer form view.

Comment: I think this means that this costumer belong to the company of the parent partener

Comment: If i create a customer without out `parent_id` it belongs to current company, right?

Comment: i tried what you did but i can see all costumers but not costumers with parent_id. because the parent company is enough

Comment: Thanks Cherrif, now i understood.